# python3 port scanner outer variable

Tags: loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I am scanning a port range after the user set a ip in an input field in python3. THIS WORKS BUT IT LOOKS NOT SO PROFESSIONAL. I have a for loop in a while and in there a try. How can I write this more elegant, without the outter class to get a break point? Thanks.

Code looks like this:

```
s = socket.socket()

class outtervar():
    connected=0

while(test.outtervar==0):
    ip = getFromInputField()
    for x in range(100): 
        try:
            s.connect((ip, port + x))
            outtervar.connected=1
            break
        except socket.error as e:
            print("Cannot connect")
            print(e)
            outtervar.connected=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function that returns on success:

```
def connect(s):
    while True:
        ip = getFromInputField()
        for x in range(100): 
            try:
                s.connect((ip, port + x))
                return
            except socket.error as e:
                print("Cannot connect")
                print(e)

s = socket.socket()                
connect(s)
```

Comment: good idea! Solved my problem as I wanted to put it into a class anyway :) Thanks!

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Ah I pressed the green check now. THANKS MIKE!